# Programmatically setting an NSTextField frame size in an NSTableCellView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, appkit, nstextfield, nstablecellview

I use storyboard to design my view-based `NSTableView` and its subviews with auto layouts. It is working fine and behaves as expected.

In my `NSTableCellView`, I have multiples `NSTextField`. I wish to programmatically change the frame in one of them. So I tried something like this.

```
dataSource = NSTableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(tableView: someTableView, cellProvider: { tableView, tableColumn, row, item -> NSView in
            guard let tableCellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: .someTableCellView, owner: self) as? SomeTableCellView else {
                fatalError()
            }

            tableCellView.randomTextField.stringValue = "Something..."
            tableCellView.someTextField.stringValue = "Blah..."

            //...

            let size = NSSize(width: 200, height: 50)
            tableCellView.someTextField.setFrameSize(size)
            tableCellView.someTextField.needsLayout = true
            tableCellView.needsLayout = true

            return tableCellView
        })
```

For `tableCellView.someTextField` and `tableCellView`, I tried the following combination and nothing seems to change:

- `.needsDisplay = true`
- `.needsLayout = true`
- `.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`
- `.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()`
- `.updateConstraints()`
- `.layout()`

Why is it so hard? My understanding is that if I set a new frame size for `someTextField` and then inform `tableCellView` that it needs to recalculate the subviews layout positions because `someTextField` has been modified so other subviews needs to reposition themselves to be consistent with auto layout constraints.

Comment: Are the layout constraints resetting the frame of the modified text field?

Comment: Are you asking me that if the auto layout constraints take priority over me manually setting the frame size of an `NSTextField`? I would say yes.

Comment: Then change the constraints instead of the frame of the text field.

Comment: My auto layout constraints does not define the size of the subviews. All it does is tell the subviews where to distance themselves from one another (e.g. Trailing Space to...) and where to align themselves relative to one another (e.g. Align leading to...).

Comment: Add size constraints to the text field?